# Intermittent "Authorization Required" exception when logging into servicem8 API from FileMaker

Tags: api, filemaker

I have a FileMaker application which pulls Jobs (and clients etc) from servicem8 using the API. As its a private application I just use username/password in the GET_URL. It usually works, but now and then will not login correctly, and I get the message:
- "Authorisation Required"

Restarting FileMaker and/or pasting the URL directly into a browser then trying again seems to resolve the problem.

The only other consistent behaviour seems to be that once it fails once, it will not work again until I restart as above.

Anyone found similar issues or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For Private applications servicem8 uses HTTP Basic Authentication. You can try to reset cached request by calling the same url from FileMaker with a different, but incorrect username and password and then repeating the original request with correct credentials.

servicem8 documentation uses curl for authentication examples and I think this will work better. To implement curl you will need a plugin, like BaseElements or MBS, although on a mac curl could be called through AppleScript.

Comment: Hi Nicolai. I did actually try that this afternoon prior to seeing your response as I guessed it was something cache related. It didn't seem to work but I will try again some other variations tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry meant to add - I am using the BaseElements plugin BE_GET_URL (). I also tried the FM Flush Cache to Disk but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

## Try using

- ```
  BE_Curl_Set_Option ( "CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH" ; 1 )
  ```

---

From [This BaseElements help article](https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204700658-BE-HTTP-GET), we can be sure that **Basic** clearly isn't the default method:

- > BE_Curl_Set_Option ( "CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH" ; 1 ) **forces Basic** auth for
  >   some sites that won't work with the defaults.

ServiceM8 will work consistently with basic auth for private applications as you say, but there are other authentications that *will only work when other valid session data is present*, which can be misleading when it works at times and not others.